# Producing K map using two numbers

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I have found this problem in my textbook.

The system has 3 inputs. The first two, A and B,
represent a number in the range 0 to 2 (3 is not used).
The third input, C represents a second number in the
range 0 to 1. The output, f, is to be 1 if and only if the
two numbers equal to each other.

(1) Create the truth table of the system.

(2) Create the k-maps of the system

(3) Get the express f(A, B, C) in minimum SOP form.

(4) Get the express f(A, B, C) in minimum POS form.

I have tried this way:

c   A   B   f

0   0   0   1

0   0   1   0

0   1   0   0

0   1   1   x

1   0   0   0

1   0   1   0

1   1   0   0

1   1   1   x

As f=1 when AB == C .

What does it mean by "The output, f, is to be 1 if and only if the
two numbers equal to each other." ? What will be the truth table?

Comment: It means that if `AB == C` then `f=1`. Otherwise it is `0`. What is not clear?

Comment: LOL could hey have written that any more confusing...

Comment: @Trevor Are you really finding it confusing? Seems very clear to me... Except the AB or BA order.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Is A Bit 0 or Bit 1.... it's not clear at all.

Comment: @Trevor Indeed that is very confusing.  I'm still stuck at the part that says "range 0 to 2 (3 is not used)"... So does that mean you only have 00, 01, 10, and you take out 11 in terms of binary for A and B

Comment: Do you mean that AB together represent a binary number that is valued from 0 to 2 (\$11_b\$ being a don't care?)

Comment: @12Lappie It means that f(1,1,x) is don't care.

Comment: Yes...I'm stuck there too... how can I represent A B from 0 to 2?

Comment: And "represent" may not even be binary.

Comment: @12Lappie, they're giving you a reason to put X's in your K-map.

Comment: It's one of those questions where you have to start out your answer with *"ASSUMING A is Binary Bit 1, and B is Binary Bit 0, and C is a single Binary bit... THEN..."*

Comment: @Trevor Which is perfectly legit for self-learning.

Comment: What will be the K map? Can anyone please clarify?

Comment: Start with truth table. We won't solve it for you (well, maybe someone will, but it is highly discouraged)

Comment: *"A system has inputs A, B and C.  A and B, represent a number in the range 0 to 2 (3 is not used). Input, C represents a second number in the range 0 to 1. The output, f, is to be 1 if and only if the two numbers equal to each other."* would have been a lot clearer.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have tried this way f =1 when A=0, B=0 and C=0 but I can't find any other 1 in output as range is from 0 to 2 for AB ...am I going right?

Comment: Do you know how to write a truth table? All of the possible inputs on the left. The corresponding outputs on the right. If you have it, include in the question and clarify what is the problem.

Comment: @EugeneSh. what about A=0 :B=1 and C=1 ?

Comment: Ok I'm not too proud to admit it .... what the heck do parts 3, and 4 mean?

Comment: @Trevor sum-of-products and product-of-sums.

Comment: AH..... I hate acronyms... .thanks @12Lappie

Comment: @Trevor why A=0, B=1 and C=1 gives f=1?

Comment: @StephensonHeulet I answered that in Lappies answer :) Playing comment tag again... LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does it mean by "The output, f, is to be 1 if and only if the two numbers equal to each other." ?

All that means is that AB == C, then f=1.  So if AB=1 & C=1, f=1.  Same thing happens if AB=0 & C=0, f=1.

So from the question, I gathered that 0 to 2 means that you have A and B in terms of Binary as 00, 01, 10, and 11 is a don't care.  With that being said, the truth table would look as follows:

- AB | C  | f
- 00 | 0  | 1
- 01 | 0  | 0
- 10 | 0  | 0
- 11 | 0  | X
- 00 | 1  | 0
- 01 | 1  | 1
- 10 | 1  | 0
- 11 | 1  | X

You can very easily extract the K-maps parameter from the truth table as it is essentially the same thing.

Comment: I'd forgotten all about k-maps.. Did then at the U... never used them since.

Comment: @Trevor You want me to include it in there as well?

Comment: Yes it will be very helpful

Comment: Na, you probably did too much already

Comment: The person asking the question wants the answer but I think you have all you need in the truth table.  K-maps are simply truth tables reorganized

Comment: @12Lappie Okay one more question why 6th line of the truth table contains 1 in output? A =0,B=1 so AB=0...did I miss something?

Comment: @StephensonHeulet do not confuse AB with A x B. AB is a binary number with two weighted bits.

Comment: Oh that's what I was doing all these time... thanks a lot

Comment: is it a OR and an AND..   or is it just binary added together?